# Node: Calling an exported function from within the declaring module

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I need to export a recursive function. Is it okay to refer to the `exports` object from within a function? (I'm worried about the circular reference).

```
exports.traverse = function(node, cb){
  if(node.hasOwnProperty("value")){
    cb(node.value);
  }else if(node.hasOwnProperty("children")){
    node.children.forEach(function(child){
      exports.traverse(child, cb);  // Err, is this ok ?
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *is* OK, it works, but there's a cleaner solution:

```
exports.traverse = function traverse(node, cb){
  if(node.hasOwnProperty("value")){
    cb(node.value);
  }else if(node.hasOwnProperty("children")){
    node.children.forEach(function(child){
      traverse(child, cb);
    });
  }
}
```